# añadir enlace href a dropdown de bootstrap

Tags: php, bootstrap

Añadir enlace href al boton principal, 
Codigo (que es el que he sacado de la pagina de bootstrap, donde pone href:photography.php esta mal, lo intenté poner ahi pero no funcionó):

```html
<div class="btn-group ">
  <button type="button" style="margin-left: 60px" class="btn btn-success" href="photography.php" >Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" style="BORDER: rgb(130,128,130) 0,5px solid; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; 
         BACKGROUND-COLOR:LightGreen; rgb(233,233,233)">
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La etiqueta `button` no debe y no puede incluir el atributo `href`, ya que éste sólo está soportado en las etiquetas `<a>`, `<animate>`, `<animateMotion>`, `<animateTransform>`, `<discard>`, `<feImage>`, `<image>`, `<linearGradient>`, `<mpath>`, `<pattern>`, `<radialGradient>`, `<script>`, `<set>`, `<textPath>`, y `<use>`.

La etiqueta `button` representa un elemento cliqueable de tipo botón que puede ser utilizado en formularios o en cualquier parte de la página que necesite un botón estándar y simple de aplicar. Aquí puedes ver los [atributos y eventos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/button#Atributos) que soporta.

El atributo `href`, en cambio, define un enlace a un recurso como una URL de referencia. El significado exacto de ese enlace depende del contexto de cada elemento que lo use.

En Bootstrap, las clases `.btn` están diseñadas para ser utilizadas con el elemento `<button>`. Sin embargo, también puede usar estas clases en los elementos `<a>` o `<input>`.

Cuando se usan clases de botones en los elementos `<a>` que se usan para activar la funcionalidad de la página (como colapsar el contenido), en lugar de enlazar a nuevas páginas o secciones dentro de la página actual, a estos enlaces se les debe asignar un `role="button"` para que puedan transmitir su propósito a las tecnologías de asistencia como los lectores de pantalla.

Una solución que puedes usar es aplicarle estilos CSS a la etiqueta `<a>` con la clase `.btn` para que visualmente parezca un botón.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Link</a>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Button</button>

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Input">
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset">
```

---

**Actualización.**

Según tu último comentario, así quedaría tu código.

Estás usando un botón y dentro le estás añadiendo la etiqueta `<a>` con estilos de botón también. Si lo que deseas es crear un enlace URL, no uses botones, sólo debes considerarlos para tomar acciones.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="btn-group ">
  <a style="margin:0px" class="btn btn-success" href="photography.php">Action</a>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" style="BORDER: rgb(130,128,130) 0,5px solid; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR:LightGreen; rgb(233,233,233)">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Fuentes:

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/href

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/buttons/#button-tags*

Comment: me gusta como queda, pero al poner el codigo que me has proporcionado han surgido nuevos problemas, los estilos propuestos en tu resupesta cambian el diseño de mi header, cosa que no entiendo, he creado una nueva pregunta todo muy bien explicado, echale un vistazo a ver si encuentras el error.https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/269934/131216

Comment: Solo como observación, las 4 primeras líneas en mi respuesta de tu código son las que trae por defecto Bootstrap. Las usé unicamente para que se visualice el snippet, revisa eso por favor, pues tus hojas de estilo en tu header.php a lo mejor son diferentes

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la etiqueta `<a>` para esto, con los estilos para que parezca botón:

```
<a style="margin-left: 60px" class="btn btn-success" href="photography.php" >Action</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vale, muchas gracias a todos, he hecho esto. Como puedo hacer que se vea bien?, sin el recuadro... Son dos botones diferentes, pero juntos a la vez.

```html
<div class="btn-group ">
  <button><a type="button" style="margin:0px" class="btn btn-success" href="photography.php" >Action</a></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" style="BORDER: rgb(130,128,130) 0,5px solid; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; 
         BACKGROUND-COLOR:LightGreen; rgb(233,233,233)">
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pero el problema es que me queda como la imagen, el boton de los submenus queda a un lado i no queda muy bien, y queda un recuadro. Paso imagen. Me pueden recomendar otras soluciones possibles para crear el botton con sus submenus. Gracias [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta. Si tienes cosas por añadir a tu pregunta, por favor edítala.

Comment: Si tu pregunta fue respondida, acepta la respuesta y si tenes una nueva pregunta, hacela.

Answer (score -2):

Y si pones la etiqueta `<a href>` encapsulando al button?

```
<div class="btn-group ">
 <a href="photography.php">
  <button type="button" style="margin-left: 60px" class="btn btn-success">Action</button>
</a>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" style="BORDER: rgb(130,128,130) 0,5px solid; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; 
         BACKGROUND-COLOR:LightGreen; rgb(233,233,233)">
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esto es una mala práctica, los elementos `<button>` no deben ser descendientes de la etiqueta `<a>`.